# Creating a treatment group to measure uplift in sales for an advertising campaign

Tags: r, treatment-effect

I have sales by state and week.

Alabama|Alaska|Arizona|...

231|139|277|...
256|154|307|...
267|160|320|...
256|154|307|...
267|160|320|...

I need to create a treatment group that bunches up the states that represent 30% of sales (which will be impacted by an advertising campaign) and a 70% control group.

How do I go about splitting them in a way that will give me the maximum correlation? The idea is to use a time series analysis and measure uplift in sales in the treatment vs. control group.

I am diving into R head first, so any way of doing so in that language would be icing on the cake.

Thanks!
J